# How to check what GPU is a program using?

Tags: 20.04, nvidia-prime, nvidia-settings

I've got dual GPU in my Lenovo Y700 laptop – NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960M and Intel(R) HD Graphics 530. I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 with proprietary NVIDIA drivers. In NVIDIA X Server Settings I set NVIDIA On-Demand PRIME profile. Now I wonder how do I check what GPU is a specific program using? I know I can use `glxinfo | grep OpenGL` to check what GPU the terminal is using (it changes if I open the terminal with a proper context menu option) but how can I say if a Steam game or any other program had opened with NVIDIA or Intel GPU?

[image: NVIDIA X Server Settings]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a low-level answer. It might need further refining if it is not exactly what you are looking for, but I can hardly help you more as I have only one GPU on my laptop.

First identify the PID (process ID) of your OpenGL program.

`/proc/PID/fd` is a directory that lists the files your program has opened. If you `ls -l` that directory, you will see files like `/dev/dri/card0`, `/dev/dri/card1`, etc. The file depends on the GPU your OpenGL program is using.

Another similar way is to execute:

```
lsof -p PID | fgrep /dev/dri
```

You can have a general view of all your programs at once with:

```
fuser -v /dev/dri/*
```